# Installing luarocks package for torch behind proxy

Tags: http-proxy, luarocks

I am looking to use the nn package for the torch framework. I downloaded and built torch from github. But when I now do :

```
    luarocks install nn
```

I get Cloning into 'nn' fatal: unable to connect to github.com error. My proxy servers are configured for wget and github. Both are working fine. I looked online and could only find [this](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/LuaRocks-through-a-proxy), so I looked for config.lua but there were many so I added to all this:

```
    proxy="proxy@port"
```

But luarocks still does not work. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found a solution. The proxy blocks git:// urls, so instead using https:// fixes the issue. The command is:
`git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/`

The url can also be modified in the git.lua file if one does not wish to change global git settings

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful :)